# Prove that $\sigma-\text {algebra}$ has the property that $\text E_1 \subseteq E \subseteq E_2$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm taking a course in Probability and I'm asked to prove the following statement :

Let $\Omega$ be a non-empty arbitrary set , then

1. $\text {$E_1$={$\emptyset$,$\Omega$}}$ is $\sigma-\text {algebra}$
2. $\text {$E_2$=P($\Omega$)}$ is $\sigma-\text {algebra}$
3. Every family of sets $\text {$E\subseteq$P($\Omega$)}$ that is $\sigma-\text {algebra}$ has the property that $\text E_1 \subseteq E \subseteq E_2$

Where $\text P(\Omega)$ is the power set of $\Omega$.

I've been able to prove the first and the second properties based on the definition of  $\sigma-\text {algebra}$ but I'm confused about the third one. Do I have to prove that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are the smallest and the largest $\sigma-\text {algebras}$ respectively ? If so , how can I do it? Any hint would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E$ be a $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$. As you noticed $E_1$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra and $E_2$ the biggest. But you are supposed to show that the inclusions $E_1 \subseteq E \subseteq E_2$ holds for any $\sigma$-algebra $E$ over $\Omega$:

The inclusion $E \subseteq E_2$ is trivial since each $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$ is a subset of $\mathcal P(\Omega)$ by definition. Moreover, one has $\Omega \in E$ by definition of a $\sigma$-algebra. Since $E$ is stable under taking complements it follows that $\emptyset = \Omega^c \in E$. Therefore, you also have $E_1 \subseteq E$.

Answer (score 1):

A sigma algebra $E$ is by definition is a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ satisfying certain properties. Hence $E\subseteq E_2$.

Next $E$ is non-empty by definition and hence contains a subset $A$ of $\Omega$. So $A^c\in \Omega$. Taking unions and intersections it follows that $\emptyset, \Omega\in E$.